# Finding the distribution of a random variable that depends on another random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that a certain animal gives birth to a number of offspring $N$. Each child survives with
probability $p$ the first year, independently of the other children. Let $Z_1$ denote the number of children alive after 1 year.

Suppose that $N$ is Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda$. What is the distribution of $Z_1$?

Any hints on how to approach this problem or refrences to similar problems would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is $Z$? Is it equal to $Z_1$?

Comment: @Shahab Yes i think it is. This is how it was written though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to average the distributions obtained for specific $N$. For example, say we use [PGFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function). If $N$ were constant we'd have a binomial distribution $Z_1\sim B(N,\,p)$, of PGF$$G_{Z_1}(t):=\Bbb Et^{Z_1}=(q+pt)^N,\,q:=1-p.$$Averaging over $N$'s Poisson distribution to solve your random-$N$ problem,$$G_{Z_1}(t)=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{[\lambda(q+pt)]^n}{n!}=e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda(q+pt)}=e^{-p\lambda}e^{p\lambda t}.$$In other words, $Z_1\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(p\lambda)$. Replacing $t$ with $e^t$ or $e^{it}$ gives a treatment instead of MGFs or characteristic functions.

Edit: to do this with PMFs instead, substitute $n=k+l$ so$$P(Z_1=k)=\sum_{n\ge0}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\binom{n}{k}q^{n-k}p^k=e^{-\lambda}\frac{(p\lambda)^k}{k!}\sum_{l\ge0}\frac{(q\lambda)^l}{l!}=e^{-p\lambda}\frac{(p\lambda)^k}{k!}.$$

Comment: Thans for your answer! If you dont mind me asking is it also possible to solve this using pmf's? I'm currently in my first course of probability and we won't discuss pgf's until a later course.

Comment: @Jedberry See edit.